# Keycloak JS library: iframe redirect when already logged in

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak

I’m working on an SPA that uses keycloak.js to interact with my Keycloak server. I initialize the Keycloak object with onload = ‘check-sso’ and checkLoginIFrame enabled.

If I perform the following steps:

- Load my site
- Click my “login” button (call Keycloak.login())
- get redirected to Keycloak’s login page, login, get redirected back to my app
- **Reload my site**

I observe that when the site reloads, it does a quick redirection (the URL briefly changes from mysite.com to mysite.com/#state=….. then back to mysite.com).
I would like to avoid having this redirection when I’m already logged in.

By debugging the code, I found out why this happens:

- The **login-status-iframe.html** page is essentially just a wrapper for some static JS to manage a cookie that stores the auth tokens.
- Its main method `checkState(...)` is called (via a message from keycloak.js) during initialization…with no token (`sessionState` is empty since keycloak.js is not aware of the cookie).
- The login iFrame’s code reads the cookie and creates an XHR request to mykeycloak.com/.../login-status-iframe.html/init?... (with the cookie in the request headers).
- When it gets a 204 response (which I take to mean: the cookie is valid, everything’s OK), it compares the token (from the cookie) with what it was given from keycloak.js (i.e. nothing).
- Since they are not equal, it responds to the callback with ‘changed’.
- This is interpreted in keycloak.js to mean that (the token changed?) and thus it calls `doLogin(false)`, which is where it changes the URL, creating the unwanted redirect.

So my questions are thus:

- Where is the documentation for API for the call to **login-status-iframe.html/init**?
- Would it be possible to do something like:

  - Have the login-status-iframe return the token, when the KC server informs it that the token is still valid (e.g. ‘update XXXXX’ instead of ‘changed’)
  - keycloak.js would then take this and update its token, without having to call `doLogin()`

Comment: I don't know the Keycloak implementation, but the session management is described in [OpenID Connect Session Management](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html). Maybe that helps.

Comment: In section 4.1: `When the RP detects a session state change, it SHOULD first try a prompt=none request within an iframe to obtain a new ID Token and session state`. The problem seems to be that keycloak.js does this directly in the window (see `login`function of the default adapter) instead of in an iframe.

Comment: I just created a Jira issue (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-10734) and did already a PR with a first approach: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/6131 - Let's see if/how it will be accepted.

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 5):

I have checked that this happens after 5 seconds and only with development server (ng serve in Angular SPA), which matches the default time of checkLoginIframeInterval.

I have tried setting checkLoginIframeInterval = false in the init() method and it fixes the loop issue but I'm afraid of side effects, I would rather update the keycloak.js file.

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/

- checkLoginIframe - Set to enable/disable monitoring login state (default is true).
- checkLoginIframeInterval - Set the interval to
  check login state (default is 5 seconds).

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have made further tests with this approach and there is bad news. It solves the infinite loop but breaks the other security checks (ie. user is not logged out automatically after session expiration). So my advice is NOT TO USE this approach.

Comment: The issue is still there and I have not found any solution or workaround so far :-(

Answer (score 3):

It will be helpful if you keep the version of keycloak same with keycloak.js. I faced with the infinite redirection as well, the version of keycloak I use is 11.0.1, well the keycloak.js was an old version. So I replace it with the file from keycloak-js-adapter-dist-11.0.1.zip(downloaded from https://www.keycloak.org/archive/downloads-11.0.1.html). Then the infinite redirection problem has gone.

Comment: that was my case, i had no problems in firefox, but in chrome it went infinite reload. It was sending a POST request to /token with refresh_token:undefined. I updated keycloak-js and keycloak-angular to the recommended versions with my keycloak server.