How to stop Vue.js reloading every 5 seconds in Chrome? Does not happen in incognito mode
I have a VueJS app. One day, it started reloading infinitely, approximately once every 5 seconds.
Here are the steps I took to debug the issue:

It does not matter which page I am on in the app.
There are no error messages in the console.
There are no network requests with error messages.
Clearing the cookies, localstorage and other application data didn't help.
Restarting the browser and computer did not help.
I reverted to an earlier commit that I know for a fact did not have this problem. Didn't help. This is not a coding error.
I tried it in Chrome incognito mode and Firefox. The issue did not occur. This is an issue between a customized Chrome and VueJS.
I tried disabling all Chrome extensions from the "Manage extensions" page. It did not help.
I tried switching to a guest profile. It did not help.
I tried creating a fresh vue.js project. This issue did not occur there. This is an issue between my Vue.js project and Chrome.
This issue only happens locally. It does not happen on the same app that is deployed to kubernetes.

Command to run the app:
nvm use 20 && vite

I'm not really sure which part of my app could be the cause and I'm really confused about why the issue doesn't occur in incognito mode. The only thing I can think of is that my app uses keycloak.
Main.ts:
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import './style.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';
import 'vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.css';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from '@/router';
import keycloak from './keycloak';
import axios from 'axios';
import { store } from './store';

keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' }).then((auth) => {
  if (!auth) {
    window.location.reload();
  } else {
    axios.defaults.baseURL = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_BACKEND;
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${keycloak.token}`;
    axios.post('/sync_account');

    const app = createApp(App);
    
    app.use(router);
    app.use(store);
    
    app.mount('#app');
  }
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error("Authentication Failed: ", err);
});


It seems like the reload could be caused by keycloak, since when the app reloads, the following three requests are made:

https://KEYCLOAK_SERVER/auth/realms/REALM/protocol/openid-connect/login-status-iframe.html/init?client_id=APP_NAME&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5173     (response is 204 No Content)
Another request to keycloak, this time with a code to the auth endpoint (response is 302 Found)
http://localhost:5173/  (the location of the app itself)

Specs:

Distribution: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Linux kernel: 5.15.0-117-generic
Chrome: Version 126.0.6478.126 (Official Build) (64-bit)

How can I further narrow down what the issue is?

I'm confident that the problem is related to the 302 status code. I suppose there's a Location header in the response, thus the redirect loop. I can't explain why it doesn't happen in incognito. Did you try the "clear site data" button? What about a fresh install of chrome?

@ChristianVincenzoTraina There is indeed a location header in that 302 Found response. I tried padlock icon -> site settings -> clear data. Nothing changed, I didn't even have to log back into keycloak.

The issue also occurs when I run chromium instead of the chrome browser

I upgraded chrome to version 127.0.6533.119 and the issue still occurs

Found a related stackoverflow issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55606931/keycloak-js-library-iframe-redirect-when-alreadylogged-in

This question is a duplicate of Keycloak JS library: iframe redirect when already logged in
The solution was to upgrade the version of keycloak-js in package.json to match the version of Keycloak I'm using:
"keycloak-js": "^25.0.0",


